# Finding the tension of the rope with a mass

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, energy-conservation

I have seen an interesting problem as follows:

> Both ends of a rope with the mass of $\rho$ kg/m and length of $L$ are attached to a horizontal surface (see photo attached). At $t=0$, one end of the rope detaches from the surface and starts falling vertically. When this end falls the height $X$, what is the tension on the other end of the rope?
>
> [image: 1]

I also have seen two different solutions from a professor which result in two different answers!

Approach 1 is based on falling part of the rope is freely falling (acceleration $= g$).

Approach 2 is based on energy conservation $KE + PE = $ Constant (no loss).

Now I would like to ask

1- Is the falling part of the rope really freely falling?

2- Is energy conserved when the rope is falling (for $X \lt L$)?

Comment: Note to those voting to close: the post isn't asking how to solve the problem.

Comment: [Chain Drop Answer 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X-QFAB0gEtE)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The rope is *not* freely falling, and energy is conserved:C. W. Wong, K. Yasui, *Falling chains*, American Journal of Physics 74 (2006) 490, and the earlier M. G. Calkin, R. H. March, *The dynamics of a falling chain I*, American Journal of Physics 57 (1989) 154.

A point not fully explained in the cited references is that when the free end of the rope is falling at speed $v$, the tension in curved bit of the rope is  $T={\mu v^2}/{4}$ on both sides of  the fold. Consequently   the falling bit of the rope has a force of $T={\mu v^2}/{4}$ pulling it down  in addition to gravity. To see  that this is so  recall   that in the absence of gravity a  chain moving with speed $u$ can maintain an arbitrary planar shape because  the centripetal acceleration of its links is automatically  provided by the tension according to
$$
\frac{\mu u^2}{r}= \frac{T}{r}, \quad (\star\star) 
$$
so the  tension takes the value $T= \mu u^2$  independent of the radius of curvature $r$.  For our falling rope, and  in the reference frame  that  is descending  with the fold at $u=v/2$, the rope/chain is moving through the fold at   $u=v/2$. If we can ignore the effect of gravity and the non-inertial reference frame, the tension throughout the fold must be $T= \mu (v/2)^2=\mu v^2/4$. Ignoring these effects  is a safe approximation for our  sharp fold because  when $r$ is small the forces in $(\star\star)$ completely dominate all other forces.